# Could ProgressDialog's style, title and message be changed on the fly?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

Is it possible to change PD's style, message and title on the fly (and not from UI thread)?
I want to do the following. Fist time PD shows in STYLE_SPINNER as it looks like endless progress and shows the message informing user that app is looking 4 something (some update 4 instance). And when it found that something it has to do something with it (install it). At this point i wanna show the HORIZONTAL styled PD as it really shows the progress state instead of spinner styled one.

Anyway I got NullPointerException while trying to PD.setMax(). PD isn't null so I can't get what's going on.

This is an inner class in my Activity class:

```
    private class RestoreDBTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>
    {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        private Handler handler;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashActivity.this);
            this.dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_wait));
            this.dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
//            this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            this.dialog.setProgress(0);
            this.dialog.show();

            handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.hide();

                    switch (msg.what) {
                    case 0:{
                        RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        break; }
                    case 1: {
                        RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        break; }
                    case -1: {
                        RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.progress_db_installing));
                        break; }
                    case -2: {
                        RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                        break; }
                    default: {
                        Log.i(APP_TAG,""+RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.getMax());
                        RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.setMax(msg.what); }
                    }

                    RestoreDBTask.this.dialog.show();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            mDBHelper.initDB(dialog,handler);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            startNextActivity();
        }
    }
```

the mDBHelper.initDB() method uses handler.sendEmptyMessage() calls with some int values assuming if msg.what>1 it is Max value for PD.
Also I can't figure out why PD doesn't show the progress state if it's style is STYLE_SPINNER? If i change it to STYLE_HORIZONTAL it works ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change PD's style, message and title on the fly (and not from UI thread)?

It's not possible to update UI stuff in another `Thread`. What you should do is to override `onProgressUpdate()` and there you can update the UI while the code in `doInBackground()` still processing.

Sample code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // Use publishProgress() to update the UI thread from
    // a working background process.

    // If you have the initDB in another class you should probably
    // pass your RestoreDBTask instance to your initDB and call the instance's
    // makeProgress() method to successfully use publishProgress().
    mDBHelper.initDB(dialog, handler, this);
    return "";
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params) {
    // If you gradually should update the ProgressDialog you probably need
    // an Integer value as argument in this method.

    // Update the ProgressDialog here.
}

public void makeProgress(Integer... params) {
    publishProgress(params);
}
```

Comment: There is no protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params) method to Override but there is protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) method. So i don't know what's next. How to cast from int or something to Void? Where the publishProgress method should be located? I guess in Activity? Then link to the ProgressDialog should be created as Activity's property? If in my mDBHelper i got link to Activity why shouldn't I use direct call, ie mDBHelper.mActivity.publishProgress() or mDBHelper.mContext.publishProgress() (i mean in initDB() method)?

Comment: Change your second type in `extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>` to `extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, String>`.

Comment: geeing CalledFromWrongThread exception or nothing happens with PD at all

Comment: Well, you're doing something wrong. Hard to tell without extended code.

Comment: I didn't understand where must be ProgressDialog created? where to store it's object link, where should be publishProgress located, what should it do, what4 is onProgressUpdate method, how could it all work if its about 3 different threads etc. So i tried many ways and all of them doesn't work. If i use link to RestoreDBTask in initDB (which is in class SQLDbHelper) i get exception about wrong thread and so on. I'm glad to provide You extended code but I don't know which version to show...

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered that PD's style couldn't be changed after show() method was executed (but only b4) because is causes a NullPointerException if app tries to call setMax()/setProgress()/increment etc. methods after that. Moreover PD's style doesn't change visually at all even in case of using hide()->change style->show() schema.
 My solution is to recreate PD in case of changing it's style (from spinner to bar or clockwise). But the problem is - I cant get Title and Message of existing PD to copy it to the new PD due to corresponding methods (getTitle/getMessage) doesn't exists and thats stupid cause setter methods do exists so it breaks Java beans rules. Why didn't they provide getters?
Unlike PD's style it's title and message could be changed on the fly.